# How to render multiple instances of the same view in a handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am attempting to render multiple instances of a containerView in a single handlebars template.

http://jsfiddle.net/skane/bZFB3/4/

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars'>
  {{ view "App.MyContainerView" }}
</script>
```

The above code works correctly as long as I don't add additional {{ view }} tags referencing the same View.  I don't understand why...  I have attached a complete fiddle that demonstrates the problem.  (check the console to see the error that is thrown).

The error that is thrown is "something you did caused a view to re-render after it was rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM".

Any help/clarification would be appreciated!

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're create()ing the child views in your container view definition, so the same child view instances are being (or attempting to be) inserted twice, one for each instance of the container view. Change those create()s to extend() and you'll be fine.

Properties set as part of an extend() block are on the prototype, so they are shared between instances. In the case of a container view, the container view will instantiate a class if it finds one where it expects to find a child view, and thus have its own instance of that child view, but if an instance is already present on the prototype, it will attempt to use that, and blow up since another instance of the containerview thinks it owns that child view instance and has already inserted it.

Comment: tremendously helpful here and in irc.  thanks for your assistance.  for the gratification of others here is  a completed fiddle showing the proper behavior http://jsfiddle.net/bZFB3/10/